# Sorting with dynamic column - Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using this [URL](https://stackblitz.com/angular/emqnabpolka?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) and I am doing sorting. Sorting is working fine but, I have 2 numeric column

1. Weight - Its value is coming from DB via API Call and it is present in dataSource. (here, sorting is working)
2. Double Weight : Its formula is: Weight * 2. 
   Here, **"Double weight"** is calculated dynamically in HTML and hence it isn't available in datasource.

I need to apply sorting in **"Double weight"** column. Can someone please guides me on this.

**HTML**

< ng-container matColumnDef="weight">

< th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight

< td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}}

< /ng-container>

< ng-container matColumnDef="weight2">

< th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight

< td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight * 2}}

< /ng-container>

**TS**

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
ngOnInit() {
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Comment: Ok, regardless fact that this is without UX purpose because it's just doubled weight... You can sort by weight and it still will be sorted properly. I mean clicking on double weight can sort by weight under the hood because result will be fine and `weight` is value which you do have.

Comment: Please tell me where I need to change the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that sorting on `(weight * 2)` will give exactly the same result as sorting by `weight`.

So while you display different values in the two columns, just sort on weight in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

This might work.